# If iterator is made on some structure to iterate over it using next function

Tags: python, iterator

For e.g. iterator is created like this:
`Iter1=iter(list)`.
Now this iterator object is created over `list` and `next` function will be called

`filter()` function returns an iterator but this iterator is created over which underlying structure to be iterated upon. The iterator is attached to which kind of data structure in case of `filter()` function that we used. To which structure iterator is attached to in case of `filter()` function?

Comment: This is implementation-dependent.

Comment: @Berner so if we are taking list in argument as iterable? Will it create iterator of filtered list?

Comment: Yes, what else would it create?

Comment: But the details of how it stores this are implementation-dependent.

Comment: @barmar I mean to ask iterator is always attach structure. I just wanted to confirm that structure. So there is no definite structure whether  it is list etc or something else. So the structure to which it is attach is not dependent on argument iterables?

Comment: Different iterators work differently. For instance, `range()` returns a `range` object.

Comment: In the case of `filter()`, the iterator is "attached" to the second argument passed to it (what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) calls the *`iterable`*).

Comment: An iterator is not necessarily attached to any thing else. It's just an object with a `__next__` method. This is an iterator:  `class Foo: def __next__(self): return 1`. An iterable is any object that implements `__iter__` to return an iterator. `filter` itself is a type that implements `__next__` by calling `__next__` on the iterator it creates from its iterable argument.

Comment: @Barmar can you answer my edited comment again,the last one. I am confused a bit.

Comment: @martineau thank you for your answer

Comment: @chepner that is a fantastic explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is a type that implements the iterator protocol. To create an instance of `filter`, you give it a predicate (or `None` to indicate the constant predicate `lambda x: True`) and an iterable. An iterator for the iterable value is created and stored along with the predicate.

When iterating over the `filter` instance, it yields only those values from its internal iterator that match the predicate. A pure Python implementation might look like

```
class filter:
    def __init__(self, p, itr):
        self.itr = iter(itr)
        self.p = p if p is not None else lambda x: True

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            x = next(self.itr)
            if self.pred(x):
                return x
```

The call to `iter` in `filter.__init__` is how you can filter an iterable (like a list) that is not itself an iterator.

---

Note that while all `filter` instances wrap some other iterator, not all iterators wrap another data structure. For example, the following class also implements the iterator protocol to produce an infinite stream of `1`s.

```
class Ones:
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        return 1
```

Comment: in filter._init_. the iter function which is written as iter(itr). In this itr means iterables like list etc. is it so? That means an iterator object is getting created which is wrapping that iterable structure?

Comment: That depends on what `itr.__iter__` actually returns, but yes, it's common for the iterator to keep a reference to an iterable. My example of `Ones` is an extreme corner case.

Comment: That is, `filter` *uses* an iterator, but expects an iterable as an argument. (By convention, all iterators should be made iterable by having their `__iter__` methods return themselves.)